# How can I optimize machine learning hyperparameters to be reused in multiple models?

Tags: matlab, optimization, machine-learning

I have a number of datasets, to each of which I want to fit a Gaussian process regression model. The default hyperparameters selected by `fitrgp` seem subjectively to produce less-than-ideal models. Enabling hyperparameter optimisation tends to result in a meaningful improvement but occasionally produces extreme overfitted values and is a computationally hungry process which prohibits an optimization for every model anyway.

Since `fitrgp` simply wraps `bayesopt` for its hyperparameter optimization, is it possible to call `bayesopt` directly to minimize some aggregate of the loss for multiple models (say, the mean) rather than the loss for one model at a time?

For example, if each dataset is contained in a cell array of tables `tbls`, I want to find a single value for `sigma` which can be imposed in calls to `fitrgp` for each table:

```
gprMdls = cellfun(@(tbl) {fitrgp(tbl,'ResponseVarName', 'Sigma',sigma)}, tbls);
```

Where `numel(tbls) == 1` the process would be equivalent to:

```
gprMdl = fitrgp(tbls{1},'ResponseVarName', 'OptimizeHyperparameters','auto');
sigma = gprMdl.Sigma;
```

but this implementation doesn't naturally extend to a result where a single Sigma value is optimized for multiple models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed this in the end by directly intervening in the built-in optimization routines.

By placing a breakpoint at the start of `bayesopt` (via `edit bayesopt`) and calling `fitrgp` with a single input dataset, I was able to determine from the Function Call Stack that the objective function used by `bayesopt` is constructed with a call to `classreg.learning.paramoptim.createObjFcn`. I also captured and stored the remaining input arguments to `bayesopt` to ensure my function call would be exactly analagous to one constructed by `fitrgp`.

Placing a breakpoint at the start of `classreg.learning.paramoptim.createObjFcn` and making a fresh call to `fitrgp` I was able to capture and store the input arguments to this function, so I could then create objective functions for different tables of predictors.

For my cell array of tables `tbls`, and all other variables kept as named in the captured `createObjFcn` scope:

```
objFcns = cell(size(tbls));
for ii = 1:numel(tbls)
    objFcn{ii} = classreg.learning.paramoptim.createObjFcn( ...
        BOInfo, FitFunctionArgs, tbls{ii}, Response, ...
        ValidationMethod, ValidationVal, Repartition, Verbose);
end
```

An overall objective function can then be constructed by taking the mean of the objective functions for each dataset:

```
objFcn = @(varargin) mean(cellfun(@(f) f(varargin{:}),objFcns));
```

I was then able to call `bayesopt` with this `objFcn` along with the remaining arguments captured from the original call. This produced a set of hyperparameters as required and they seem to perform well for all datasets.